# Is there an Android Tikkun App that has sound?

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, torah-reading, phone

During the "pre smart phone days" (Yes, that DID exist), I used *Trope trainer* to practice some of my laining and to train my kids and some Bar Mitzvah boys.

I recently downloaded the "Tikkun Korim" app on my Droid Maxx (Offhand, I don't know the manufacturer.) It is fine for most of what I need.

However, I'd like an app like this that links to sound files with someone singing all or part of the verses. Is there an app that does this?

Also, the Tikkun app that I have, doesn't show the parsha breaks (*petuchot and stumot*). I guess they wanted to save screen space?, but I'm not sure why. Is there a Tikun app that shows the parsha breaks in both "regular" and "Ktav Ashurit"?

I'd prefer a free app, but if it's low cost, I'd consider that, too.

Comment: To the contrary, you're smarter than your phone :) I don't know where to look for Android software, but there is an equivalent app for the iPhone by Rustybrick, although it costs ~$20 and recordings of the kriah and haftarah are all in-app purchases (which wouldn't help me as a Yecke ;þ)

Comment: Rustybrick seem to have an Android app at https://www.rustybrick.com/android-tikun.php

Comment: How is this on-topic?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30847/discussion-on-question-by-danf-is-there-an-android-tikkun-app-that-has-sound).

Answer (score 1):

There is the free app [Pocket Torah](http://www.pockettorah.com/?page_id=29), which allows for the downloading of sound files. The quality varies. Due to some portions being read by women, some might see it as a problem of Kol Isha.

Comment: [Followup question.](/q/64889)

Comment: Careful with this one. I've spotted errors. Listen with a critical ear. It's probably the best app for the ashkinazi melody. Yemenite shout-out to http://www.moryapp.co.il/, but probably not what OP is looking for.